# Path not found to when opening sumo traffic simulation package

Tags: macos, sumo, zshrc

I have installed sumo software following the MacOS guidelines. However when attempting open sumo I get the following error. I have also added the path to sumo and sumo-gui to the `.zshrc` file.
`export PATH="$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin/sumo"`
`export PATH="$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin/sumo-gui"`

`source .zshrc` #Restart terminal

```
Could not identify the location of SUMO (SUMO_HOME environment variable not found)

Please set this environment variable in .zshrc, .bash_profile or .profile
```

```
The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “”
```

Any ideas how I can fix it?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sumo, but your path is a list of directories that _include_ executables, and should not include the executables themselves. For example, if you have a `sumo-gui` script or binary in `/opt/homebrew/bin`, then `/opt/homebrew/bin` is what gets added to your path, not `/opt/homebrew/bin/sumo-gui`. And from the docs, it looks like `SUMO_HOME` (which isn't related to PATH) is supposed to be the source repo for sumo.

Answer (score 0):

Please try a re-installation with brew. It will mention in the end that you need to set SUMO_HOME to a path ending with `share/sumo` probably `/opt/homebrew/share/sumo`. You then need to add to your .zshrc the line `export SUMO_HOME=/opt/homebrew/share/sumo`. It is also in the docs: https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Installing/index.html#macos